# cannot resolve symbol getContext

Tags: java, android, gallery, photo, android-context

I am new to android/java programming and I am having an issue with getting an error saying that the symbol`getContext` cannot be resolved, I am trying to get the pictures from my app to save to the photo gallery on the phones primary external storage. If anyone could help me out with this error I would be very grateful for any input:

```
public void saveImage(){
    String fileName="Site" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,fileName);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,"image/jpg");
    Uri uri=getContext().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
    try {
        OutputStream outStream=getContext().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        Toast message=Toast.makeText(getContext(),R.string.message_saved,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        message.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,message.getXOffset() / 2,message.getYOffset() / 2);
        message.show();
    }
    catch (  IOException ex) {
        Toast message=Toast.makeText(getContext(),R.string.message_error_saving,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        message.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,message.getXOffset() / 2,message.getYOffset() / 2);
        message.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I advice you to create something like this class:

```
public class ContextGetter extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Whenever you need to get the `Context` just use the `getAppContext()` method.

By the way you will need to make some changes in the manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".ContextGetter"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

And add all your other content inside the `application` tag